# ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis .. when i don't have any missing parenthesis or spelling mistakes

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax-error, ddl, create-table

When I run this SQL it gives me this error and I can't figure it out

```
CREATE TABLE PAYMENT (
Payment_ID int(16) not null,
Amount_paid varchar2(30) not null,
Payment_ReceivedBy varchar(30) not null,
Payment_ReceivedFrom varchar(30) not null,
Payment_Date datetime not null, 
Card_Number varchar2(20) not null,
Card_Holder_Name varchar2(30) not null,
Is_CreditCard number(20) ,
Is_DebitCard  number(20),
Online_Payment varchar(10),
CashOnDelivery varchar(10),
CONSTRAINT PaymentID_PK PRIMARY KEY (Payment_ID)
);
```

error:

```
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

Comment: What is `int(16)`?

Comment: that's the int limit.. is this wrong?

Comment: int is for storing numbers btw

Comment: `16` wouldn't even be a limit in MySQL

Comment: okay. i got it now thank you

Answer (score 1):

The error message isn't great, and the issue in fact isn't really about parenthesis - it's about datatypes. Oracle doesn't have `int` and `datetime` types. Instead, you could use `number(16)` and `date`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE PAYMENT (
Payment_ID number(16) not null, -- Here
Amount_paid varchar2(30) not null,
Payment_ReceivedBy varchar(30) not null,
Payment_ReceivedFrom varchar(30) not null,
Payment_Date date not null,  -- And here
Card_Number varchar2(20) not null,
Card_Holder_Name varchar2(30) not null,
Is_CreditCard number(20) ,
Is_DebitCard  number(20),
Online_Payment varchar(10),
CashOnDelivery varchar(10),
CONSTRAINT PaymentID_PK PRIMARY KEY (Payment_ID)
);
```

Comment: it worked thank you

Comment: Well, Oracle does support the `int` (and `integer`) data type - but it's just an alias for `number` - and `int(16)` in MySQL did **not** limit the range of the values in any way

Comment: okay thank you so much